# How to get app id and session id mediafire

Tags: mediafire

i try make my python upload and download file to mediafire
i have try pymediafire from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymediafire too,
but How to get application ID and Session id from my mediafire account ?, 
anyone can   explain me, thank's

Answer (score 1):

Go to your account settings, you will find tag 'Developer', fill the developer information, you will be allowed to create new application. Create new application, you will get the application id and session key

Comment: Looks like there is no option to create something now I guess.

Comment: It's 3 years since I answered this question. However, according to  [the developer document](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/core_api/1.5/getting_started/), I have an account of mediafire and can not see the Developer, I think there is a limitation or have to do something to see Developer tag. You can find the answer [here](https://www.mediafire.com/developers/getting_started/getting_started/)

Comment: In the SO, [in this question answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38061684/1116137), they are said that the api is closed, but I can't find any news or blog post from mediafire.

Comment: Actually they disabled that I guess. I'm able to create a new developer profile but cannot create an application. I signed up for pro account without knowing this. I asked to cancel my subscription and asked for refund, and they did without any explanation from their end. So...

Answer (score 0):

by default, there is no developer option at all.

first, you have to visit [Developer Application Link](https://www.mediafire.com/myaccount/applications.php) and register a developer account.

then you will see the developer option at [profile page](https://www.mediafire.com/myaccount/)

hope this will help many peoples.