# Mediafire developer doesn't show me Create new app

Tags: mediafire

I have placed a ticket to mediafire tech support (twice) without answer: I have created two different accounts, totally different info, one free and one Pro (pay). None of them show me the Create new application box in My account->settings->developer. The emails I have used are verified...any clues? Thx

Comment: How long did you give support to answer your tickets?

Comment: You know it's the weekend, right?

Answer (score 15):

Ok, they are not giving API keys anymore:

"Currently we are not offering the API key option. We may offer it again in the future but at this time it has been disabled."

Wasn't better if they just said so in the place, instead of showing a link that doesn't say anything about it? Oh well...